# undefined local variable or method `session' for Devise::FailureApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use Rails 3.2.11 and Devise 3.2.3

When i try to navigate to page that requires admin authentication i always get:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<Devise::FailureApp:0x0000000590f380>
```

from

```
devise (3.2.3) lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb, line 38
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got the [Devise Initializer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) in your app?

Comment: @RichPeck Yes i have config/initializers/devise.rb

Comment: @AlexanderPanasyuk Please paste the content of the page and the controller.